# Time Limit Exceeded on Leetcode problem 141

Tags: c

Here is my code, and it works on my local compiler.
but got "Time Limit Exceeded" on Leetcode.

My idea is to **make every node point to the head node** and then 
traverse, so that if getting head node means there is a cycle.

```
bool hasCycle(struct ListNode *head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return false;

    struct ListNode *now;
    struct ListNode *pre;
    now = head;

    pre = now;
    now = now->next;
    pre->next = head;

    while(now != NULL){
        if (now == head){
            return true;
        }

        pre = now;
        now = now->next;
        pre->next = head;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't sound like a good way to detect a cycle.  But, the "time limit exceeded" error definitely sounds like your code has an infinite loop in it.

Comment: What do you need `pre = now;` assignment for if you never use `pre`?

Comment: loop detection in a simple linked list is done by slow+fast pair of pointers advancing through the loop. Initially they start on the "head". From there, the slow is advanced one hop for every two the fast is advanced. If they *ever* point to the same node again there must be a loop.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seems no loop in code.

Comment: @zerkms sorry for that, I completed my code already.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for your idea, it's really a clever thought!

Comment: [Floyd's Tortoise and Hare algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many forms of circular linked lists, you can't conclude that head is an item in the linked list.

maybe as this

```
head -> a -> b -> c
        ^         |
        |         |
        -----------
```

You can define fast and slow pointers, fast in steps of 2, and slow in steps of 1. If the list is a loop, fast will eventually be equal to slow.

```
bool hasCycle(struct ListNode* head) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    struct ListNode* fast;
    struct ListNode* slow;
    fast = head->next->next;
    slow = head->next;

    while (fast && fast->next) {
        if (fast == slow) {
        return true;
        }

        fast = fast->next->next;
        slow = slow->next;
    }

    return false;
}
```